# mysql insert - skip duplicates syntax error - sprintf (WHERE NOT EXISTS )

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a row but not insert data that already exists. Is it possible to do the below with sprint? I need help with the syntax for this.

```
    $insertSQL = sprintf("
    INSERT INTO post_view (trade_id, user_id, timestamp)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    SELECT trade_id,
           user_id,
           timestamp
    FROM post_view
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id
         FROM post_view
         WHERE trade_id = %s
         AND user_id = %s)", 
GetSQLValueString($_GET['trade_id'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user_id'], "int"), 
GetSQLValueString(time(), "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_GET['trade_id'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user_id'], "int"));

mysqli_select_db($connection, $database_connection);
$Result = mysqli_query($connection, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Currently getting below error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT trade_id, user_id, timestamp FROM post_view WHERE NOT' at line 3

Comment: Should  you throw a semi-colon after your insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `INSERT` statement can either have `VALUES` to insert literal values, or a `SELECT` clause to get the values from a query, but it can't have both. Put the values you want into the `SELECT` statement using the special table `DUAL` as the source.

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("
    INSERT INTO post_view (trade_id, user_id, timestamp)
    SELECT %s, %s, %s
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id
         FROM post_view
         WHERE trade_id = %s
         AND user_id = %s)", 
GetSQLValueString($_GET['trade_id'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user_id'], "int"), 
GetSQLValueString(time(), "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_GET['trade_id'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['user_id'], "int"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an editing mistake and accidentally put back the VALUES line. Try it now.

Comment: perfect - this is the one, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO post_view (trade_id, user_id, timestamp)
   VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
             FROM post_view
             WHERE trade_id = %s
             AND user_id = %s);
```

You might need to change the values.

Comment: error:( You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM post_view WHERE trade_id =

Comment: You can't use `IF` and `BEGIN` outside a stored procedure.

Comment: Changed the query according to that.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM post_view WHERE tra' at line 3

Comment: Appreciate your help @birla